# Network namespace & slirp4netns - access namespaced network from host

Tags: network-namespaces

I create a network namespace using `unshare --map-root-user --net --mount --keep-caps "do_stuff"`.
I connect the namespace to the internet using `slirp4netns --configure --mtu=65520 $ns-id tap0`.
This also allows me to access `localhost` from withing the namespace via `10.0.2.2`, so I can run a web server on the host and connect to it from withing the namespace.

Is it possible to run a web server *in the namespace*, and connect to it from the host? Something like a port forward?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method sidestepping entirely the namespace limitation to forward a TCP port.

### [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) and UNIX socket

One kind of communication not hindered by the namespace is standard (named) UNIX socket (only *abstract* UNIX sockets depend on the network namespace) . Using a pair of `socat` commands to proxy TCP through UNIX sockets allows to communicate easily from host to user/net namespace.

Assuming OP's variable `$ns_id` (changed with a `_` to have a correct syntax) has the correct PID content. Here's an example interactively run using two additional terminals:

- term1: (the user/net namespace part)

  `socat` could be forked directly from OP's user/net namespace in the `"do_stuff"` command to spare the use of `nsenter`.

  Here it's run from host/initial namespace using [`nsenter`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html) to join the recently created namespace(s):

  ```
  nsenter --preserve-credentials --user --mount --net -t  $ns_id -- socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/conduit,unlink-early,fork TCP4:127.0.0.1:80
  ```
- term2 (the host/initial namespace part):

  ```
  socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/conduit
  ```

Now one can connect to http://<host>:8080/ to reach the user/net namespace's web server listening on port 80. Traffic goes through the UNIX socket `/tmp/conduit`.

---

### Notes

- This setup doesn't even involve `slirp4netns` at all which doesn't even have to be running as long as the user/net namespace received a `ip link set dev lo up` command to get TCP/IP available *somewhere*. One could even imagine configuring the Web server (probably [`nginx`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) then) itself to directly listen to an UNIX socket rather than TCP port 80 and keep only the second `socat` command (though I don't give any guarantee on the correct handling of any [socket credentials](https://manpages.debian.org/unix.7#Ancillary_messages) if those are used).
- One should likewise be able to proxy UDP traffic in a limited way but there are various caveats depending on UDP use. Some uses would just need to change the TCP parts of `socat` commands into UDP, other uses  need to also change the UNIX socket part from stream sockets to datagram sockets (`UNIX-LISTEN` -> `UNIX-RECVFROM` etc.). The `-T` timeout option in `socat` is probably also needed. Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [socketbox](https://github.com/PHJArea217/socketbox) tools specifically designed to enable exposing services inside isolated network namespaces without setting up `veth`.

Maybe my own tool [netns_tcp_bridge](https://github.com/vi/netns_tcp_bridge) can also attain something like that (with lower efficiency), but I have not checked whether it can be used with unprivileged user namespaces.